# handshake: The WebSocket handshake was declined by the remote peer

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, boost-beast

Code Snippet :

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

namespace beast     = boost::beast;     // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http      = beast::http;      // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net       = boost::asio;      // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp           = boost::asio::ip::tcp; // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Report a failure
void
fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what)
{
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    tcp::resolver                        resolver_;
    websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream> ws_;

    beast::flat_buffer buffer_;
    std::string        host_;
    std::string        message_text_;

  public:
    // Resolver and socket require an io_context
    explicit
    session(net::io_context& ioc)
        : resolver_(net::make_strand(ioc))
        , ws_(net::make_strand(ioc))
    {
    }

    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void
    run(
        char const* host,
        char const* port,
        Json::Value message)
    {
        // Save these for later
        host_         = host;
        message_text_ = Json_to_string(message);

        // Look up the domain name
        resolver_.async_resolve(
            host,
            port,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_resolve,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_resolve(
        beast::error_code ec,
        tcp::resolver::results_type results)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "resolve");

        // Set the timeout for the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).async_connect(
            results,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_connect,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_connect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type ep)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "connect");

        // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
        // the websocket stream has its own timeout system.
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never();

        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws_.set_option(
            websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
                beast::role_type::client));

        // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](websocket::request_type& req)
            {
                req.set(http::field::user_agent,
                    std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                        " websocket-client-async");
            }));

        // Update the host_ string. This will provide the value of the
        // Host HTTP header during the WebSocket handshake.
        // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
        host_ += ':' + std::to_string(ep.port());

        // Perform the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_handshake(host_, "/",
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_handshake,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    std::string Json_to_string(const Json::Value& json) {
        Json::StreamWriterBuilder wbuilder;
        wbuilder["indentation"] = ""; // Optional
        return Json::writeString(wbuilder, json);
    }

    void
    on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec) {
            return fail(ec, "handshake");
        }
        
        // Send the message
        ws_.async_write(
            net::buffer(message_text_),
            beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_write, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_write(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "write");
        
        // Read a message into our buffer
        ws_.async_read(
            buffer_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_read,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_read(
        beast::error_code ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "read");


        ws_.async_read(buffer_,beast::bind_front_handler(
            &session::on_read,shared_from_this()
        ));
    }

    void
    on_close(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "close");

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully

        // The make_printable() function helps print a ConstBufferSequence
        std::cout << beast::make_printable(buffer_.data()) << std::endl;
    }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    // auto const host = argv[1];
    // auto const port = argv[1];
    // auto const text = argv[1];

    std::ifstream file("details.json");
    Json::Value actualjson;
    Json::Reader jsonreader;

    jsonreader.parse(file,actualjson);

    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context context;

    // Launch the asynchronous operation
    std::make_shared<session>(context)->run("stream.binance.com", "9443",
                                            actualjson);

    // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
    // the socket is closed.
    context.run();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

my details.json file for subcribing market data streams :

```
{
    "method": "SUBSCRIBE",
    "params":
    [
    "btcusdt@aggTrade"
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

This is the binance API docs i am referring to :
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#aggregate-trade-streams

I am trying to stream trade market streams over the websocket.

I don't know why the request is being rejected by the server, please help and advance thanks!

Comment: [wss://stream.binance.com:9443](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#:~:text=The%20base%20endpoint%20is%3A%20wss%3A//stream.binance.com%3A9443) implies that the endpoint uses SSL. You're not using SSL

Comment: nice, thanks! i should try that one out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should

- use SSL, usually [with SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)
- not append the port to the hostname for WS handshake (mildly surprising)
- use a proper endpoint url, [from the same docs](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#websocket-market-streams):

  > The base endpoint is: `wss://stream.binance.com:9443`
  >
  > - Streams can be accessed either in a single raw stream or in a combined stream
  > - Raw streams are accessed at `/ws/<streamName>`
  > - Combined streams are accessed at `/stream?streams=<streamName1>/<streamName2>/<streamName3>`
  > - Combined stream events are wrapped as follows: `{"stream":"<streamName>","data":<rawPayload>}`

I just guessed a stream name (`wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt`), added some code to print the received/sent messages:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

namespace beast     = boost::beast;     // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http      = beast::http;      // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net       = boost::asio;      // from <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace ssl       = net::ssl;
using tcp           = net::ip::tcp; // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

using Stream = websocket::stream<beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream>>;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Report a failure
void
fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what)
{
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    tcp::resolver resolver_;
    Stream        ws_;

    beast::flat_buffer buffer_;
    std::string        host_;
    std::string        message_text_;

  public:
    // Resolver and socket require an io_context
    explicit
    session(net::io_context& ioc, ssl::context& ctx)
        : resolver_(net::make_strand(ioc))
        , ws_(net::make_strand(ioc), ctx)
    {
    }

    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void
    run(
        char const* host,
        char const* port,
        Json::Value message)
    {
        // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
        if (!SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ws_.next_layer().native_handle(), host)) {
            throw boost::system::system_error(beast::error_code(
                ::ERR_get_error(), net::error::get_ssl_category()));
        }

        // Save these for later
        host_         = host;
        message_text_ = Json_to_string(message);

        // Look up the domain name
        resolver_.async_resolve(
            host,
            port,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_resolve,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_resolve(
        beast::error_code ec,
        tcp::resolver::results_type results)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "resolve");

        // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to ssl handshake successfully)
        if (!SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ws_.next_layer().native_handle(),
                                      host_.c_str())) {
            throw beast::system_error{beast::error_code(
                ::ERR_get_error(), net::error::get_ssl_category())};
        }

        // Set the timeout for the operation
        get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(30s);

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).async_connect(
            results,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_connect,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_connect(beast::error_code ec, [[maybe_unused]] tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type ep)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "connect");

        // Update the host_ string. This will provide the value of the
        // Host HTTP header during the WebSocket handshake.
        // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
        //host_ += ':' + std::to_string(ep.port());

        // Perform the SSL handshake
        ws_.next_layer().async_handshake(
            ssl::stream_base::client,
            beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_ssl_handshake,
                                      shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_ssl_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "ssl_handshake");

        // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
        // the websocket stream has its own timeout system.
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never();

        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws_.set_option(
            websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
                beast::role_type::client));

        // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](websocket::request_type& req)
            {
                req.set(http::field::user_agent,
                    std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                        " websocket-client-async");
            }));

        // Perform the websocket handshake
        std::cout << "using host_: " << host_ << std::endl;
        ws_.async_handshake(host_, "/ws/btcusdt",
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_handshake,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    std::string Json_to_string(const Json::Value& json) {
        Json::StreamWriterBuilder wbuilder;
        wbuilder["indentation"] = ""; // Optional
        return Json::writeString(wbuilder, json);
    }

    void
    on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec) {
            return fail(ec, "handshake");
        }
        
        // Send the message
        std::cout << "Sending " << message_text_ << std::endl;
        ws_.async_write(
            net::buffer(message_text_),
            beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_write, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_write(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "write");
        
        // Read a message into our buffer
        ws_.async_read(
            buffer_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_read,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_read(
        beast::error_code ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "read");

        std::cout << "Received: " << beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_.cdata())
                  << std::endl;
        ws_.async_read(
            buffer_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_close(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "close");

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully

        // The make_printable() function helps print a ConstBufferSequence
        std::cout << beast::make_printable(buffer_.data()) << std::endl;
    }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    // auto const host = argv[1];
    // auto const port = argv[1];
    // auto const text = argv[1];

    std::ifstream file("details.json");
    Json::Value   actualjson;
    Json::Reader  jsonreader;

    jsonreader.parse(file, actualjson);

    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc;

    // The SSL context is required
    ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::tlsv12_client};

    // Verify the remote server's certificate
    ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
    ctx.set_default_verify_paths();

    // Launch the asynchronous operation
    std::make_shared<session>(ioc, ctx)->run("stream.binance.com", "9443",
                                             actualjson);

    // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
    // the socket is closed.
    ioc.run();
}
```

Now the output is

```
using host_: stream.binance.com
Sending {"id":1,"method":"SUBSCRIBE","params":["btcusdt@aggTrade"]}
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
Received: {"result":null,"id":1}{"e":"aggTrade","E":1650214540406,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":1143057169,"p":"40330.30000000","q":"0.00910000","f":13276
```

etc...

Note: you will want to fix the code to **not** hardcode the `/ws/btcusdt`path

Comment: thankyou!! 

i just tried to build this, but i am getting this error : https://gist.github.com/dogmasucks/4a7a6e50161f7667823910824146fc99

Comment: That's very [easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) to [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=undefined+reference+to+%60CONF_modules_unload%27): You have to link openssl

Comment: sure, thanks sehe!